# how to get the frame of a view controller in viewWillAppear when the view controller is presented use UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: ios

I want to get the frame of a view controller. The view controller is presented by another view controller with the option 'UIModalPresentationFormSheet'.

I cannot get the correct frame in method 'viewWillAppear'. The size of the view controller is 1024x768. Only in the method 'viewDidAppear' I can get the right frame of the main view. I want to do some layout in viewWillAppear, the frame is required. I do not want to hard code the size.

Comment: 1024 x 768, that sounds like an iPad or something, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not get the correct frame in viewWillAppear, system will give you correct frame in viewDidAppear and viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews.

If your presented view is same as screen height,width you can use [UIScreen mainScreen].bound to get the correct dimensions in viewWillAppear. but it is advised as @rounak mentioned put your layout code in viewWillLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 3):

Put your layout code in viewWillLayoutSubviews on UIViewController

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hardcode, height and width, just macro that stuff, assuming that you are presenting a full screen modal:

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ((([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
```

you can call them like so:

SCREEN_HEIGHT and SCREEN_WIDTH;

From the looks of your question, the UIViewController being presented is the same size as an IPad, so this window is the same size as the window of the app, so your frame is this:

```
CGRectMake(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT)
```